# Zabbix JMX JBoss monitoring

Tags: zabbix

do any of you tried to monitor

'Jboss.as.expr: subsystem = datasources, data-source = aft-ds ". ?

I tried to do it with such Item

jmx ["jboss.as.expr: type = datasources name = aft-ds", "jdbc", "PreparedStatementCacheMissCount"]

But zabbix can not interpret it. Does anyone have any idea how to plant do?

Answer (score 2):

JMX items in Zabbix take two arguments, object name and attribute name, and have a general format of `jmx[<object name>,<attribute name>]`. In your example, you try to pass three arguments, which is not correct.

If you can view the value you are trying to monitor in JConsole, then transforming it into a Zabbix item is trivial. Take the following picture as a simple example:

[image: JConsole]

The object name (marked with red) goes into the first argument and attribute name (marked with blue) goes into the second argument. Try that with your JBoss object.

Note that the only JMX connection URL supported by Zabbix is of the form `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://{$HOST}:{$PORT}/jmxrmi`, so if JBoss uses a different URL scheme you have to either wait until [ZBXNEXT-1274](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1274) is implemented or use one of the workarounds suggested there.

Please also see the [official documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring) for more details on setting up JMX monitoring in Zabbix.